# How to convert 'void *' return from a C function to 'UnsafeMutableRawPointer' in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, c, macos, swift3, xcode8

I'm trying to convert a lua bridge from Swift 2 to Swift 3. I am not the original author so there are aspects of the library I don't know very well and the original author seems not interested to continue working on the project. I have most of the conversion done but there remain one place I'm stuck and could not figure out. I've tried searching on SO and on the Internet but could not find anything that could help me solve the problem.

If anyone is interested in looking at the full source code, here is my fork of the project on github: https://github.com/weyhan/lua4swift (My changes is in the Swift3 branch)

Allow me setup the context to the error I'm stuck on. There is a Userdata class, specifically in the method `userdataPointer<T>() -> UnsafeMutablePointer<T>` the c function `lua_touserdata` returns the block address of userdata as a `void *` pointer type.

Original code written in Swift 2:

```
public class Userdata: StoredValue {

    public func userdataPointer<T>() -> UnsafeMutablePointer<T> {
        push(vm)
        let ptr = lua_touserdata(vm.vm, -1)
        vm.pop()
        return UnsafeMutablePointer<T>(ptr)
    }

    public func toCustomType<T: CustomTypeInstance>() -> T {
        return userdataPointer().memory
    }

    public func toAny() -> Any {
        return userdataPointer().memory
    }

    override public func kind() -> Kind { return .Userdata }

}
```

After the conversion with Xcode 8 migration tool, Xcode is complaining about the return line with error `Cannot invoke initializer for type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<T>' with an argument list of type '(UnsafeMutableRawPointer?)'`:

```
return UnsafeMutablePointer<T>(ptr)
```

I've fixed it with:

```
return (ptr?.assumingMemoryBound(to: T.self))!
```

Following that above change, now Xcode 8 is now complaining about the calling statement in `createCustomType`:

```
public func createCustomType<T: CustomTypeInstance>(setup: (CustomType<T>) -> Void) -> CustomType<T> {
    lua_createtable(vm, 0, 0)
    let lib = CustomType<T>(self)
    pop()

    setup(lib)

    registry[T.luaTypeName()] = lib
    lib.becomeMetatableFor(lib)
    lib["__index"] = lib
    lib["__name"] = T.luaTypeName()

    let gc = lib.gc
    lib["__gc"] = createFunction([CustomType<T>.arg]) { args in
        let ud = args.userdata

        // ******* Here's the line that is causing problem in Swift 3
        (ud.userdataPointer() as UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>).destroy()
        // *******

        let o: T = ud.toCustomType()
        gc?(o)
        return .Nothing
    }

    if let eq = lib.eq {
        lib["__eq"] = createFunction([CustomType<T>.arg, CustomType<T>.arg]) { args in
            let a: T = args.customType()
            let b: T = args.customType()
            return .Value(eq(a, b))
        }
    }
    return lib
}
```

Where I'm getting stuck is the line :

```
(ud.userdataPointer() as UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>).destroy()
```

I believe the original author is attempting to clear the memory block where the pointer returned by `userdataPointer()` call is pointing to.

With the Xcode 8 auto migration tool the above line is converted as below:

```
(ud.userdataPointer() as UnsafeMutableRawPointer).deinitialize()
```

However Xcode now is then complains that `Cannot convert call result type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<_>' to expected type 'UnsafeMutableRawPointer'`.

From my research, the change to the return line in `userdataPointer` seems correct, so I think the issue is with the cast to UnsafeMutableRawPointer. I've tried dropping the cast to `UnsafeMutableRawPointer` and invoke `ud.userdataPointer().deinitialize()` directly but I get this error `Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred`.

Other things I've tried is to convert the UnsafeMutablePointer to UnsafeMutableRawPointer but It always result in Xcode 8 complaining one thing or another. Any suggestion on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you may have already found out, Swift 3 attempts to provide better type safety when it comes to pointers.  `UnsafeMutablePointer` can now only represent a pointer to an instance of a known type.  In Swift 2, a C `void *` was represented by `UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>`, allowing void and non-void pointers to be treated in the same way, including trying to call a de-initializer of the pointed-to type, which is what the `destroy()` method in the problematic line of code does:

```
  (ud.userdataPointer() as UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>).destroy()
```

In Swift 3 the de-initializer on the pointee is called using the `deinitialize()` method of the `UnsafeMutablePointer` structure.  It appears that the migration assistant got confused.  The line

```
(ud.userdataPointer() as UnsafeMutableRawPointer).deinitialize()
```

makes little sense because (1) `UnsafeMutablePointer` cannot be converted using `as` to `UnsafeMutableRawPointer`;
 (2) `UnsafeMutableRawPointer` has not `deinitialize()` method.  In Swift 3, `UnsafeMutableRawPointer` is a special type to represent `void*`.  It is actually quite understandable why the migration tool made this mistake: it blindly replaced `destroy()` with `deinitialize()` and `UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>` with the corresponding Swift 3 type `UnsafeMutableRawPointer`, without realizing that the conversion would not work.

I don't quite understand why calling `destroy()` on a void pointer would work in Swift 2.  Maybe this was a bug in the program or some compiler trick allowed the correct de-initializer to be called.  Without knowing enough about the code, I can't be more specific than to suggest analyzing it to figure out what is the type pointed to by that pointer on which `destroy()` was called.  For example, if we know for sure that it is always the placeholder type `T` used on the following line:

```
   let o: T = ud.toCustomType()
```

then the offending line simply becomes

```
  (ud.userdataPointer() as UnsafeMutablePointer<T>).deinitialize()
```

We need the conversion in the parentheses to allow the compiler to infer the generic parameter.

Thank you for bringing up an interesting problem.  BTW, once you get over this obstacle, you are likely to run into other problems.  One thing that jumps out is that `UnsafeMutablePointer` has no `.memory` in Swift 3; you'll have to use `.pointee` instead.

Here's an update.  After playing with Swift 2.2 on Linux, I realize that calling `destroy()` on an `UnsafeMutablePointer<A>` cast as `UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>` won't call A's deinitializer, even if it has one.  So, you have to be careful with that line...

Comment: The Swift 3 migrator seems to convert those `.memory` to `.pointee` right. You are right that the migrator got confused in a few places but generally it works in most of the conversion.

I've managed to fix it by changing the offending line to: `UnsafeMutablePointer<T>(ud.userdataPointer()).deinitialize()`
I think this is correct but if you know it's wrong I'd appreciate if you let me know. Thanks for the long analysis!

Comment: What you did works the same as what I suggested.  Either way we need a cast or initialization just to tell the compiler what the generic parameter is when calling `userdataPointer()`.  Be careful, however: the problematic line in the old code didn't de-initialize user data.  The new code will.  If the subsequent `toCustomType()` call tries to return the same userdata object, it will be already de-initialized.  Of course, I don't know the code, just sharing general observations.

Comment: The old code meaning this line? `(ud.userdataPointer() as UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>).destroy()`. Thanks for the heads up. I'll be looking into it.

Comment: Yes, as far as I can tell, that code wasn't doing anything.  Its replacement will actually de-initialize userdata...

Comment: Thanks! I'll definitely be looking out for any side effects.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating an instance of `UnsafeMutableRawPointer` instead of trying to cast it:

`UnsafeMutableRawPointer<T>(ud.userdataPointer()).destroy()`

Comment: Although the form I use was this:
`UnsafeMutablePointer<T>(ud.userdataPointer()).deinitialize()`
Thanks.